# How do I set page content using Prism and Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, prism

So, currently in my MainPageViewModel, I have something like this:

```
        WrapLayout wrapLayout;

        private string _title;
        public string Title
        {
            get { return _title; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _title, value); }
        }

        public MainPageViewModel()
        {
            wrapLayout = new WrapLayout();

            Content = new ScrollView
            {
                Margin = new Thickness(0, 20, 0, 20),
                Content = wrapLayout
            };
        }
```

Where MainPageViewModel inherits from BindableBase... However, I also want it to inherit from ContentPage, so I can set the page content to my wraplayout. However, it won't allow me to inherit from two base classes.

I'm confused on how to proceed then?

Here's my XAML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:VideriMediaViewer"
             x:Class="VideriMediaViewer.MainPage">

    <ScrollView Margin="0,20,0,20">
        <local:WrapLayout x:Name="wrapLayout" />
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage>
```

What can I do in this scenario? I want to bind to the tile in my xaml (have MVVM structure) but also set content page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've completely missed the entire point of MVVM. Your ViewModel should NEVER EVER have any View or any understanding of the View. The entire point is loosely coupled code allowing a separation of concerns.

I suggest that you head over to the [Prism Samples for Xamarin Forms](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism-Samples-Forms) to get a better understanding of how to properly set up an app.

Comment: Just to confirm, then I would set up my wrap layout inside of my XAML then? Thanks a lot!

Comment: yes a WrapLayout is a View and therefore belongs in your XAML. You would then Bind to one or more properties that are in your ViewModel. Again see the Prism Samples.

Comment: Is there a good Prism sample where they call services that hit an api endpoint and return the data to the view? Thanks! Also, just something to note, it's hard to find good samples online that are not from the old Prism. The new Prism templates are a bit different in syntax. Thanks a lot again!

Comment: The Contoso Cookbook is up to date with Prism 7 and all of the netstandard and SDK Style project goodness.... the other samples are will also answer other questions you may have. If there is a particular issue you have with a sample feel free to file an issue there.